# Number of Partition of a Set with Repeated Elements

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition, multisets

It is well known that for a set of $n$ elements, say $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, the total number of possible partitions of this set is equal to $B_n$, where $B_n$ is the Bell number, and a set partition is a grouping of the $n$ elements into non-empty subsets.

For the more general problem when we have a set with $k_1$ elements of 1, $k_2$ elements of 2, and $k_n$ elements of $n$, so the set has $k = k_1+\ldots+k_n$ elements.  How do we figure out how many set partitions are there?  More importantly, is there a simple algorithm to enumerate the entire set partitions for this set of $k$ numbers with repeated elements?

Comment: It will not be easy.  Try a small example such as with $k_1=2$ and $k_2=3$ to see some of the difficulties in a systematic approach (I think there may be $15$ multiset partitions, $7$ where the two type 1 elements are together and $8$ where they are separate, though I may be wrong).

Comment: I believe there are 16 of them when $k_1=2$ and $k_2=3$.  Here is the list: (11222), (1122)(2), (1222)(1), (112)(22), (122)(12), (222)(11), (112)(2)(2), (122)(1),(2), (222)(1)(1), (11)(22)(2), (12)(12)(2), (12)(22)(1), (11)(2)(2)(2), (12)(1)(2)(2), (22)(1)(1)(2), (1)(1)(2)(2)(2).

Comment: At OEIS there are some sequences for special cases e.g. [A035098](https://oeis.org/A035098) for the case $k_1=\cdots=k_{n-1}=1$ and $k_n=2$. You can check the CROSSREFS section there to get more particular cases.

Comment: @RaymondKan Your $16$ seems to be correct [I missed (12)(12)(2) when I tried earlier], so $16$ multiset partitions, $7$ where the two type 1 elements are together and $9$ where they are separate.  Still not simple.

Comment: I found the algorithm to generate this multiset partitions.  It is Algorithm M in p.429 of Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming" Volume 4A.  However, expression for counting the number of mulitset partitions does not seem to be available.

Comment: As another example, when $k_1=\dotsb=k_{n-1}=1$ and $k_n=3$, you get https://oeis.org/A169587 for which the formula $a(n)=(Bell(n)+3Bell(n-1)+5Bell(n-2)+2Bell(n-3))/6$ is given, where $Bell(n)$ is the $n$-th Bell number; the exponential generating function is $(e^{3x}+6e^{2x}+9e^x+2)(e^{e^x-1})/6$.